# Handlebars- block helper inside block helper

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm new to Handlebars and I wanted to know if I can use block helper inside a block helper, something like this:

```
{{#each person}}
     {{each family_member}}{{family_relation}}
     {{/family_member}}
{{/person}}
```

I've tried to do it with a simple helpers in http://tryhandlebarsjs.com

and it didn't work, but I couldn't find any place saying if it can work or not....
any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use block helpers inside block helpers. Provided they are used the correct way.

```
{{#each person}}
  {{#each family_member}}
    {{family_relation}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

You can actually see a plunkr here : http://plnkr.co/edit/H9XlaQG99etHb4Fwx9pp?p=preview